# Function to list all post slugs for every post in my WP database?

Tags: slug

Function to list all post slugs for every post in wp_posts table?

I assume there's an official function to generate a post slug, but maybe someone here already has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

example - unordered list with post slugs:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach( get_posts('numberposts=-1') as $post ) { 
    echo '<li>' . $post->post_name . '</li>'; 
  } ?>
</ul>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Michael.  I'm actually moving posts out of WP so technically I'm not "in the loop".  Surprisingly, I found the answer through Google Plus almost immediately after I posted the question:

PJ Brunet - +Lloyd Budd I didn't see the slug in wp_posts, I'll check the_permalink() that's probably what I need. 
Lloyd Budd - +PJ Brunet the column is post_name. 

PJ Brunet - That worked. For example "select post_name from wp_posts LIMIT 500;" That's pretty much what I needed.

Comment: reference to database tables: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Tables